# How to type generator function in Cython?

Tags: python, cython

If I have a generator function in Python, say:

```
def gen(x):
    for i in range(x):
        yield(i ** 2)
```

How do I declare that the output data type is `int` in Cython? Is it even worth while?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I read mentions of (async) generators being implemented in the changelog: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/changes.html?highlight=generators#id23

However there is no documentation about how to use them. Is it because they are supported but there is no particular advantage in using them with Cython or no optimization possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in Cython.

When you look at the Cython-produced code, you will see that `gen` (and other generator-functions) returns a generator, which is basically a `__pyx_CoroutineObject` object, which [looks as follows](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/bd023b4e4f375ce0c90e85a2bf6302565f9276be/Cython/Utility/Coroutine.c#L365):

```
typedef PyObject *(*__pyx_coroutine_body_t)(PyObject *, PyThreadState *, PyObject *);
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    __pyx_coroutine_body_t body;
    PyObject *closure;
    ...
    int resume_label;
    char is_running;
} __pyx_CoroutineObject;
```

The most important part is the `body`-member: this is the function which does the actual calculation. As we can see it returns a `PyObject` and there is no way (yet?) for it to be adapted to `int`, `double` or similar.

As for the reasons why it is not done, I can only speculate - but there are probably more than just one reason.

If you really care about performance, generators introduce too much overhead anyway (for example `yield` is not possible in `cdef`-functions) and should be refactored into something simpler.

---

To elaborate more about possible refactorings. As baseline let's assume we would like to sum up all created values:

```
%%cython 
def gen(int x):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(x):
        yield(i ** 2)

def sum_it(int n):
    cdef int i
    cdef int res=0
    for i in gen(n):
        res+=i
    return res
```

Timing it leads to:

```
>>> %timeit sum_it(1000)
28.9 µs ± 1.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The good news: it is about 10 times faster than the pure python version, but if we are really after the speed:

```
%%cython 
cdef int gen_fast(int i):
    return i ** 2

def sum_it_fast(int n):
    cdef int i
    cdef int res=0
    for i in range(n):
        res+=gen_fast(i)
    return res
```

It is:

```
>>> %timeit sum_it_fast(1000)
661 ns ± 20.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

about 50 times faster.

I understand, that is quite a change and might be pretty hard to do - I would do it only if it is really the bottle-neck of my program - but then speed-up 50 would be a real motivation to do it.

Obviously there are a lot of others approaches: using numpy-arrays or `array.array` instead of generators or writing a custom generator (cdef-class) which would offer an additional fast/efficient possibility to get the `int`-values and not `PyObjects` - but this all depends on your scenario at hand. I just wanted to show that there is potential to improve the performance by ditching the generators.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was under the impression that generator are generally more efficient, at least with memory. 

So, if I were to refactor my function to return, say a set or a list, which return type should I declare?

Comment: @user3758232 I elaborated a little bit more about what I meant by "refactoring". If you fall back to return the whole data, I would choose `array.array` or numpy-arrays because they store not the Python-objects but raw ints/doubles and so on - less memory needed and faster.

Comment: Very, very helpful. Thanks. Actually I already have an inner function that I can optimize the way you suggest first, and an outer loop which can get called many times too. For that I can look into arrays.